# Cannot download file in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to figure out how to download files in Django.I went through a couple of answers on stackoverflow and tried out this:

views.py

```
def download():

    file = open("DemoCSV.csv", "r")

    response = HttpResponse(file,content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="DemoCSV.csv"'
    return response
```

The file DemoCSV.csv is in the same folder as my app.

When I hit the url from the browser,I cannot download the file.This error message is shown:

```
TypeError at /resources/download_files
download() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `download` is a view, as such it's expected to take a single parameter, an HttpRequest object. so change as follows

```
def download(request):

    file = open("DemoCSV.csv", "r")

    response = HttpResponse(file,content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="DemoCSV.csv"'
    return response
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: Also for anyone looking at this question,enter full path of the file in the "open" statement.